# Div in grid item not taking height of grid item

Tags: html, css

The div with class name `items` has dimensions of `36.90x0` when I use inspect and it's bugging me. What I want to do is create a div to the left of each `accounts-grid-item` but it never takes up the height of `accounts-grid-item`. I have tried putting `height:100%` in the child-div `.items` but to no avail. I also read that a parent element must have a specified height so a child knows what to inherit but in this case, my `html` tags (not shown here) have a `vh` of 100vh and hence, I am assuming it can work with that? Is there a way I can control the height of `items` relative to `accounts-grid-item`?

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.account-intro {
  height: 10%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.accounts {
  height: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1976d2;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1em;
}

.accounts-grid-item {
  background-color: #16330014;
  padding: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5%;
  height: 60%;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
}

.items {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="account-intro">
      <p>
        Account</p>
    </section>
    <section class="accounts">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let account of accountDetails">
        <div class="accounts-grid-item">
          <div class="items">
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't totally follow.  You have an 80px padding within your grey rectangle, and this is why the red rectangle is not the full height of the grey. If you don't want this, you can just remove the padding, but I suspect I am not understanding the full problem.  If removing the padding isn't what you need, can you give a mockup/screenshot of your target UI, so that we can work towards that?

Comment: Oh my, that was exactly the issue. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot. @Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.accounts-grid-item` has `80px padding`, making the red rectangle unable to take up the full height.